# Selenium chrome: I just can't use driver.maximize_window() to maximize window

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I don't know why I just can't use *driver.maximize_window()* to maximize window.It worked before .And Exception is :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvUZI.jpg)

Comment: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot get automation extension
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
  (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.133)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download chrome driver 2.28 from below path. This issue got fixed in this version

----------ChromeDriver v2.28 (2017-03-09)----------

Supports Chrome v55-57

Resolved issue 1625: Error: cannot get automation extension on Chrome57+ [['OS-All', 'Pri-1', 'merge-merged-2987']]

Resolved issue 1695: Chrome crashes on Linux32 bot [['OS-Linux', 'Pri-1']]

Resolved issue 1467: A hang occurs when an alert dialog is displayed on Chrome 52+ [['OS-All', 'Pri-2']]

Resolved issue 1688: Exported Netlog with --log-net-log is truncated [['OS-Linux', 'OS-Mac', 'Pri-2']]

Resolved issue 1388: find Elements is failing [['Pri-2']]
.

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Answer (score 0):

While using crome driver it is recomended to maximize the Browser windown through ChromeOptions class as below:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
driver.get(url);
```

PS: This is the Java syntax, convert it accordingly.

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thank you. It works in this way.When I failed to used the method I asked, I use this method instead.